# DataTables - Ajax pagination broken

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the DataTable jQuery library to display data and using the server side processing option to do it using ajax. Everything works fine except that my pagination does not stop at the last page. I can continue to navigate beyond (of course all of these pages are empty). The info displayed at the bottom of the table are also wrong, saying : `Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries (filtered from NaN total entries)`

Javascript initialization:

```
    const ajaxUrl    = $(this.tableContainer).data('ajaxUrl');
    const pageLength = $(this.tableContainer).data('pageLength');

    $(this.tableContainer).DataTable({
        'ajax'         : ajaxUrl,
        'pageLength'   : pageLength,
        'processing'   : true,
        'serverSide'   : true,
        'lengthChange' : false,
        'info'         : true,
        'searching'    : false,
        'autoWidth'    : false,
        'columns'      : [
            {
                "data" : "fileName",
            },
            {
                "data" : "userName",
            },
            {
                "data"      : "hash",
                "orderable" : false,
            },
            {
                "data" : "date",
            },
            {
                "data"      : "time",
                "orderable" : false,
            },
            {
                "data"      : "transactionNumber",
                "orderable" : false,
            },
            {
                "name"      : "download",
                "orderable" : false,
                "render"    : this.renderButton.bind(this)
            }
        ],
        "order"        : [[3, 'desc']] // Order by date by default
    });
```

My JSON response looks fine, it is generated from a PHP/Symfony app.

```
{
  "draw": "1",
  "recordTotal": 51,
  "recordFiltered": 51,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 601,
      "fileName": "vvvvvvv.png",
      "userName": "Angelo Mahrouchi",
      "date": "02/03/2020",
      "time": "10:20:08",
      "transactionNumber": "0x4d58e7450054dfa73455bbe82f8bffb8bd75cefba098398171c594eba1c56780",
      "hash": "48f0b5225832ae836b4fe1203ef5ec98d04b7bd231511de8d13cb858fdd562a37210550e9f9711f9e83610b7faaa96091de8721e814c2a673190c755059c0b7c"
    },
    {
      "id": 551,
      "fileName": "TestFile 0",
      "userName": "Certification Fixture",
      "date": "01/03/2020",
      "time": "09:01:50",
      "transactionNumber": "0x90d3ae190428986851b26e0350e831116cbff4a124da299439f557b6e11d658b",
      "hash": "9d5dc53cb2f265ee42cc6e34bc2d8b6d3b78b733f166fed4817c908a16c15fb2464b607c06a0f6d7e4a5800641810db87be1a48807380c2c892ce2e672531868"
    },
    // ...
}
```

What am I missing... ?

Comment: The JSON in the question looks incorrect: (1) There is a missing `]` - perhaps that was only a copy/paste problem; (2) the labels `recordTotal` and `recordFiltered` look wrong.  I think they should be `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered`.

Comment: OMG... I feel so dumb.... I have been struggling for hours just because I mispelled the 2 keys... Thank you >.<

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned on the comments above the error was quite simple... I mispelled the keys `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered` in the ajax response and of course it does not work >.<